# Use case of namespace in Socket IO Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm going through following document

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
send(message, namespace='/chat')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
emit('my response', json, namespace='/chat')
```

What is the purpose of namespace in this example. An example with HTML socket connection would be helpful or any online doc is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are a feature of the Socket.IO protocol. You can read about them in the Socket.IO website: https://socket.io/docs/v3/namespaces/.

The idea is to be able to use the Socket.IO connection for different purposes, at the same time, and without things getting mixed up.